# Python Divide and Conquer Implementation of Nth Power of X

Tags: python, divide-and-conquer

As a new python programmer, I'm working on a Leetcode question and don't know why my code does not work, so I really appreciate your advice:

Question:

Implement pow(x, n), which calculates x raised to the power n.

Example:
Input: 2.00000, 10

Output: 1024.00000

Here is my python code (I tried to use divide and conquer concept):

```py
class Solution:
    def myPow(self, x, n):
        if n == 0:
            return 0
        if n == 1:
            return x
        return self.power(x,n)
    def power(self,x,n):
        if n == 1:
            return x
        self.power(x,n//2)
        self.multiply(x,x)
        return x
    def multiply(self,x,y):
        x = x*y
        return x
test3=Solution()
test3.myPow(2,4)
```

But the results give 2 instead of 16. I expect the above code to work as follows:

power(2,4)->power(2,2)->power(2,1), which reaches the base case since n==1, and then we proceed with power(2,2),due to function multiply(x,x) or multiply(2,2) in this case, I expect x to become 4 (x = 2*2), and then we proceed with power(2,4), due to function multiply(x,x), x = 4*4 = 16

I don't know why I am wrong, could any expert give me some advice?

Comment: Why are you using a class for this? Is it the format/structure mandated by leetcode?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile,yep, the solution for each leetcode question starts with class:)

Comment: Ah that explains it. I hope it doesn’t lead to people picking up bad habits!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x^0 always equals 1, so your first "if" in myPow() is not accurate.
Also, your power() function always returns x, because the lines:

```
self.power(x,n//2)
self.multiply(x,x)
```

don't assign the value they return to anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Solution:
    def myPow(self, x, n):
        if n == 0:
            return 1
        if n == 1:
            return x
        return self.power(x,n)

    def power(self,x,n):
        if n == 1:
            return x
        x = self.power(x,n//2)
        return self.multiply(x,x)

    def multiply(self,x,y):
        x = x*y
        return x

test3=Solution()
test3.myPow(2,4)
```

This code only fixes some minor problems in your code, but still you should consider cases when the power `n` is an odd number.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't storing the return values from your `self.power()` and `self.multiply()` within `power()`.

This is due to function scope. When you change `x` within `multiply()`, it is only changed within that function. You are correctly returning the changed value but you don't store it in the calling function.

Changing `power()` to the following works for your example (2^4).

```
def power(self,x,n):
    if n == 1:
        return x
    x = self.power(x,n//2)
    x = self.multiply(x,x)
    return x
```

However, your algorithm is flawed as 2^3 returns `4` rather than `8`.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would note that `x ^ 0 = 1`, but your code states that it should equal zero within your first `if` statement within `myPow`. Second, your big problem is that you are not storing any of your intermediate results. Within the `power` function, you have:

```py
def power(self,x,n):
  if n == 1:
    return x
  self.power(x,n//2)
  self.multiply(x,x)
  return x
```

This function is taking in `x` and `n`, then computing subproblems using these variables, and then returning the original `x`. Therefore, in your example, calling `test3.power(x, y)` will always return the original `x` value. Instead, do the following.

```py
def power(self,x,n):
  if n == 1:
    return x

  # Account for when n is not even.
  n1 = n // 2
  n2 = n - n1

  # Calculate powers.
  x1 = self.power(x, n1)
  x2 = self.power(x, n2) 

  # Combine divide-and-conquer answers and return.
  x = self.multiply(x,x)
  return x
```

Also notice that I changed the function to break the problem into powers of `n1` and `n2`. This is because your function would not correctly handle something like `power(2, 3)`. In this case, the original function would compute `power(2, 3 // 2) = power(2, 1)` which is not what you want. I hope this helps.